# Visual Studios WCF Shared Library Classes DataContractAttribute

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studios C# Class library(A5Lib) and a WCF Service project(A5Services). the A5Services project references A5Lib and the web service functions use the classes created in A5Lib(as arguments/return objects).

My ASP Web project is also going to utilize the classes in A5Lib, so I don't want to move those objects to the Web Service.

The problem is that when I try to Run A5Services, I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:16344/UserServices.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: http://localhost:16344/UserServices.svc    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:16344/UserServices.svc'.    Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:16344/UserServices.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.    The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.HTTP GET Error    URI: http://localhost:16344/UserServices.svc    There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:16344/UserServices.svc'.    The request failed with the error message:--#content{ FONT-SIZE: 0.7em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 30px}BODY{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white}P{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 12px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana}PRE{BORDER-RIGHT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BORDER-TOP: #f0f0e0 1px solid; MARGIN-TOP: -5px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; FONT-SIZE: 1.2em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 5px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #f0f0e0 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Courier New; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e5e5cc}.heading1{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 15px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 26px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; MARGIN-LEFT: -30px; WIDTH: 100%; COLOR: #ffffff; PADDING-TOP: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #003366}.intro{MARGIN-LEFT: -15px}ServiceService
>
> The service encountered an error.
>
> An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a WSDL export extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior contract: http://tempuri.org/:IUserServices ----> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type 'A5Lib.Appliance' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String message, Type type)   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.GetDataContract(Type clrType)   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.GetItemTypeDataContract(CollectionDataContract collectionContract)   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.AddCollectionDataContract(CollectionDataContract collectionDataContract)   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.InternalAdd(XmlQualifiedName name, DataContract dataContract)   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.AddClassDataContract(ClassDataContract classDataContract)   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.InternalAdd(XmlQualifiedName name, DataContract dataContract)   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.Add(Type type)   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractExporter.Export(Type type)   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportType(Type type, String partName, String operationName, XmlSchemaType& xsdType)   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractExporter.ExportBody(Int32 messageIndex, Object state)   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessage(Int32 messageIndex, Object state)   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessageContract()   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.System.ServiceModel.Description.IWsdlExportExtension.ExportContract(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext)   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CallExtension(WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext, IWsdlExportExtension extension)   --- End of inner ExceptionDetail stack trace ---   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.MetadataExtensionInitializer.GenerateMetadata()   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.EnsureInitialized()   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.InitializationData.InitializeFrom(ServiceMetadataExtension extension)   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.GetInitData()   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.TryHandleDocumentationRequest(Message httpGetRequest, String[] queries, Message& replyMessage)   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.ProcessHttpRequest(Message httpGetRequest)   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.Get(Message message)   at SyncInvokeGet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)--.

Here is what I pulled out of that:

> Type 'A5Lib.Appliance' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.

Visual studios does not let me marked those classes/data members in A5Lib(compile error) with those attributes(even with using System.Runtime.Serialization). Any reason why?

Comment: Silly question, but it's bitten me before - did you add a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization as well as the using statement?

Comment: O I did not add a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization, but in VS, it showed up as I typed "using System.Runtime.Serialization" so I assumed it had found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added [Serializable] to all the classes, and it works magically........

Answer (score 0):

I had to explicitly add the System.Runtime.Serialization assemebly reference. Not sure why becase as you say VS seems to resolve it when you type the using statement ??